# How to pass named params to powershell script using Terraform variables

Tags: azure, powershell, terraform

I'm trying to figure out the proper way to pass terraform variable value to my Powershell script.

The script fails when I try to deploy it using Microsoft extension.
Below is my terraform script:

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "test" {
    name = "testt"
    virtual_machine_id = azurerm_virtual_machine.example.id
    publisher = "Microsoft.Compute"
    type = "CustomScriptExtension"
    type_handler_version = "1.9"            
    protected_settings = <<SETTINGS    
{    
"commandToExecute": "powershell -command \"[System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString([System.Convert]::FromBase64String('${base64encode(file("shell.ps1"))}')) | Out-File -filepath shell.ps1\" && powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File shell.ps1 -value1 ${var.value1} -value2 ${var.value2}"
    }    
SETTINGS    
}
```

Below is the  Powershell script:

```
param(

  [string]$value1,
  [string]$value2
)
```

The error I am facing:

> "message": "param : The term 'param' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check \r\nthe spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Comment: Please [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this?

```
param(
  [string]$value1 = ${var.value1},
  [string]$value2 = ${var.value2}
)
```

Comment: Still facing the same error